# Why these commands in mercurial create a new head?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I was asked as an assignment to figure out which of the following lines causes the number of heads to change, now I checked and saw that lines 16 and 20 add new heads to their repository, but I'm not quite sure why.. I understand that the number is changed when there's a conflict but it's a bit unclear here..

Can anyone please help me understand? :)

Thanks.

```
1: /home/user> hg clone http://remoteserver/mainrepository first 
2: /home/user> cd first 
3: /home/user/first> echo one > a.txt # Create a new ﬁle a.txt containing “one” 
4: /home/user/first> hg add a.txt 
5: /home/user/first> hg commit -m "Added a file" 
6: /home/user/first> cd .. 
7: /home/user> hg clone first second 
8: /home/user> cd second 
9: /home/user/second> echo two >> a.txt # Append a line to a.txt containing “two” 
10: /home/user/second> hg commit -m "Modified a file" 
11: /home/user/second> hg push -f http://remoteserver/mainrepository 
12: /home/user/second> cd ../first 
13: /home/user/first> echo more > b.txt # Create a new ﬁle b.txt containing “more” 
14: /home/user/first> hg add b.txt 
15: /home/user/first> hg commit -m "Added another file" 
16: /home/user/first> hg pull # default pulls from where repo was cloned 
17: /home/user/first> echo ‘‘even more’’ > c.txt # Create a new ﬁle c.txt 
18: /home/user/first> hg add c.txt 
19: /home/user/first> hg commit -m "Added yet another file" 
20: /home/user/first> hg push -f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps 1-5 leave the main and first repositories in the following state, assuming a r1-r3 was the original state of main:

```
Main:  r1--r2--r3

First: r1--r2--r3--r4
```

Steps 6-11 copy first to second, commit something to second, and push it back to main:

```
Main:   r1--r2--r3--r4--r5

First:  r1--r2--r3--r4

Second: r1--r2--r3--r4--r5
```

Steps 12-15 go back to first and commit something again:

```
Main:   r1--r2--r3--r4--r5

First:  r1--r2--r3--r4--r6

Second: r1--r2--r3--r4--r5
```

Step 16 pulls from main into first, bringing in the missing `r5`, but note both `r6` and `r5` have the same parent of `r4`, so this creates a branch:

```
Main:   r1--r2--r3--r4--r5

First:  r1--r2--r3--r4--r6
                      \-----r5

Second: r1--r2--r3--r4--r5
```

Steps 17-19 create another commit on first:

```
Main:   r1--r2--r3--r4--r5

First:  r1--r2--r3--r4--r6------r7
                      \-----r5

Second: r1--r2--r3--r4--r5
```

Step 20 *forces* a push back to main, creating a branch there as well:

```
Main:   r1--r2--r3--r4--r5
                      \-----r6--r7

First:  r1--r2--r3--r4--r6------r7
                      \-----r5

Second: r1--r2--r3--r4--r5
```

Instead, a better practice is to merge locally in first so the main repository isn't left with two heads.  So between steps 19 and 20 perform `hg merge` and then `hg push` without forcing with `-f`.  The result would then be:

```
Main:   r1--r2--r3--r4--r5----------m8
                      \-----r6--r7-/

First:  r1--r2--r3--r4--r6------r7--m8
                      \-----r5-----/

Second: r1--r2--r3--r4--r5
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take these steps a bunch at a time and explain what happens:

Step 1-2: Clone a repository, and update the working folder to the tip, then enter that folder.

Step 3-5: Commit another changeset, creating a new tip (but not another head).

Step 6-8: Clone the first repository into a new one, update the working folder of this as well, then enter that folder.

Step 9-10: Commit another changeset on top of tip in the second clone.

Step 11: Push this new changeset into the original source. This repository, the one we cloned from to create `first` thus now has one changeset in addition to those we cloned in step 1.

Step 12: Go back to the first repository

Step 13-15: Commit another changeset above the current changeset in the first.

Step 16: Pull from the original source, here we bring in the changeset we first added in the second clone and then pushed in step 11 above. This will make our `first` repository now have two heads.

Step 17-19: Commit yet another changeset on top of the previous one, this does not create another head, we're just "extending" that head with another changeset.

Step 20: Pushes to the original source, forcing the push, which will push new changesets and create another head in the remote repository.

---

Now, *why* does this happen and is this *OK*?

First, OK? Yes, definitely. Well, sort of. Creating additional heads in a local repository is both OK and recommended. For instance, if you discover that you introduced a bug some time ago the recommended method for fixing it is first updating back to the changeset that introduced the bug, then fixing the bug in the working folder, and then committing the bugfix on top of the original changeset.

The "sort of" above comes from the fact that additional heads should be resolved locally before pushed. You should almost never *push* additional heads into remote repositories. As such, the `-f` parameter to `hg push` is best left alone.

The correct way to fix additional heads is to merge, this takes two parents and merges the changes introduced in those two parallel branches back into one head.

So, *why* does this happen? Well, the best way to learn that is just to read up on how distributed version control systems work.

In short, if you clone a repository down to your local machine, and then work locally, at the same time that other people work and push new changesets of their own up into the repository you cloned from, then eventually when you try to push you will be told this introduces additional heads, which is bad.

To resolve this you should pull, and merge your head with the head that was pulled down (that head will contain the new changesets others contributed in the meantime), before you reattempt your push.